# Level of crafted and gambled items in low-level game

Tags: diablo-iii

It is said that if you were a level 12 and created a game, all items that you would get are items with a base level of 12 and below.
If I brought a level 70 character into that game, would upgrading a level 70, we could say, ceremonial knife through Kanai's cube make it into a legendary with a base level of 12 and below?
Secondly, will the items that I would get from kadala be level 70 or level 12?

Please correct me if that assumption is wrong, if not then answer the two questions I had just stated. Thank you!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with either RNG or drop rates, why did you put these in title? Also, please don't duplicate tags in title.

Comment: This thread talks about the RNG and

Comment: You mean that thread on Diablo forums you mentioned? In this question you asked here there is nothing about randomness. Levels of crafted and gambled items are fixed either to level of base item or level of character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, items you upgrade would be level 70, and items from kadala would be level 12 or under, but be aware, some items don't drop/given by kadala under certain levels.

Comment: Also to note is that if your friend upgrades items through his cube it can't be traded anymore.